# Ormlite query help for newbie

Tags: ormlite

Having a few problems with Ormlite and Android/Sqlite so any help appreciated. The database structure is

```
"CREATE TABLE [jobTasks](" +
        "[JobTaskID] varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT (newid())," +
        "[JobID] varchar(50) NOT NULL," +
        "[EnumTaskType] Real," +
        "[TaskID] varchar(50)," +
        "[TaskOrder] SmallInt," +
        "[TaskDescription] NVarChar (50) ," +
        "[EnumTaskStatus] Real," +
        "[EnumTaskQualifier] Real," +
        "[IsTaskQualifierForced] Bit," +
        "[CompletedBy] NVarChar (50)," +
        "[CompletedOn] DateTime," +
        "[CompletedOnOffset] NVarChar (6)," +
        "[JobAssetID] varchar(50),[wadtDeleted] Bit NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0))," +
        "[WadtModifiedBy] NVarChar (15)," +
        "[WadtModifiedOn] DateTime," +
        "[WadtModifiedOnDTOffset] NVarChar (6)," +
        "[WadtRowID] varchar(50) DEFAULT (newid())," +
        "[ParentJobTaskID] varchar(50)," +
        "[Rowguid] varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT (newid())," +
        "SyncDeleted Bit NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0))," +
        "FOREIGN KEY(JobID) REFERENCES jobJob(jobID)," +
        "FOREIGN KEY(enumTaskType)  REFERENCES enumTaskType(enumTaskType)," +
        "FOREIGN KEY(TaskID) REFERENCES cfgWorkFlowTasks(TaskID)," +
        "FOREIGN KEY(enumTaskStatus) REFERENCES enumTaskStatus(enumTaskStatus))"
```

The query is

```
QueryBuilder<JobParentTask, String> qb =
    _databaseContext.JobParentTasks().queryBuilder();
qb.orderBy(JobParentTask.TASKORDER, true);
qb.where().eq(JobParentTask.JOBID, id).and()
     .isNull(JobParentTask.PARENTJOBTASKID);
PreparedQuery<JobParentTask> preparedQuery = queryBuilder.prepare();
CloseableIterator<JobParentTask> iterator
    =_databaseContext.JobParentTasks().iterator(jobParentTaskPreparedQuery);
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    parentTasks.add(iterator.next());
}
```

The following error is thrown

```
 unrecognized token: "6B582835": , while compiling:
 SELECT * FROM `jobTasks` WHERE
 `JobID` = 6B582835-5A79-E011-A5E4-005056980009 AND `ParentJobTaskID` IS NULL )
 ORDER BY `TaskOrder`
```

If I am passing the id as a string value why does it not show as such in the query?

The final error thrown is

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not build prepared-query iterator for class
conx.Entities.JobParentTask
```

I assume this is related to the original error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please accept either your own or my answer @Kern.  Glad you found the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will hang my head in shame. The JOBID was associated as a column name annotation for the wrong column.

Answer (score 0):

Huh.  I suspect you have an existing database table that you are trying to match a Java class against?  Any chance that the `JobID` field in your Java class is *not* a string but is, by accident, an integer?

The `eq(JobParentTask.JOBID, id)` method should look at the field inside of `JobParentTask` and see that it is a `String` that needs to be escaped.  This is core code in ORMLite that has been working for some time.

Can you post the `JobParentTask` definition around the JobID field?

If you still are having problems an immediate workaround is to use the "Select Args":

> http://ormlite.com/docs/select-arg

Something like:

```
SelectArg jobIdArg = new SelectArg(id);
queryBuilder.where().eq(JobParentTask.JOBID, jobIdArg).and()...
```

Then the query that is constructed used a ? and injects the argument using SQL.